# 4 way anova? 5 way anova? What is it?

Tags: anova

```
Score | Food in the past two hours | chocolate or painting| experience|Maze time high or low
14             1                           1                   1              1
20             2                           1                   2              2
30             1                           1                   2              1
21             2                           2                   1              2
34             1                           2                   1              1
32             2                           2                   2              1
```

Before I start, I just want to say that this is how my data looks like in SPSS. I have managed to carry out a correct ANOVA (hopefully) but I cannot identify the type of ANOVA I have carried out. Score is the DV, and the IV's are categorised into 2 groups for example yes or no (1 or 2) in terms if participant had food in the past two hours or not. Manipulation condition, where someone either has been shown a painting or picture (1 or 2). Previous experience, so yes or not (1 or 2) and time it took a participants to complete a maze which is also categorised into two groups, high and low (so again, 1 and 2). All participants have done everything the same, however when it comes to 'chocolate or painting' this is where the two groups differ. There was 30 ppts and 15 seen a painting and the other 15 have seen chocolate. However, I categorised this as 1 and 2 in SPSS so hopefully it makes sense. But, the question is...what kind of ANOVA have managed to carry out? I know it's a bit strange but as I am reporting the findings in the results section I seem to not be able to figure out my own design which is embarrassing. I can give more details if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

The "way" of an ANOVA is the number of independent variables. You have 1. Food  2. Painting v. picture  3. Previous experience  4. Time it took.  So, that would be 4-way.

Some other thoughts, not directly related to your question but perhaps important:

- You then mention 'chocolate vs. painting' - is that another variable,
  or is this a typo?
- Categorizing a continuous variable (time) is almost always a bad
  idea.
- You haven't mentioned your dependent variable
- There may be some issues of overfitting.